# How to access the kernel menuconfig in a Yocto project using bitbake?

Tags: yocto

I am currently trying to build a very simple system using Yocto. For this, I would like to change the kernel config, so I run:

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

However, I can't get this to open the kernel menuconfig.

- When using `xterm` or `rvxt` for `OE_TERMINAL`, a terminal opens very shortly and closes.
- Using `tmux` yields nothing
- Using screen yields:

```
Trying to run: screen -r devshell_11581
There is no screen to be resumed matching devshell_11581.
```

With no way I can actually access the kernel menuconfig. Also I could not find any logs.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the official Yocto reference manual [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-OE_TERMINAL).

Try to set OE_TERMINAL to "auto" to let bitbake detect your default terminal. Or when using one of:

- gnome
- xfce
- xvt
- screen
- konsole

make sure that it is installed on your system.

I think, from my little experience:

- gnome (for gnome-terminal)
- xfce (for xfce-terminal)
- xvt
- screen
- konsole (for KDE environment)

Edit: Also make sure that you install all Yocto dependencies, specially libncurses-dev for menuconfig menu.

Comment: `auto` does not work either. The menuconfig works fine when I compile a kernel manually and of course I have screen/rxvt/etc installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue and I've been avoid it for too long.

I'm basically having a terminator (X terminal) through ssh with forwarded X.

There's a definite fix:

Install **libncurses5-dev**.

That's it.

https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/yocto-kernel-config-without-menuconfig/m-p/910414/highlight/true#M137177